# > Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native

Getting follwoing error

C:\Users\projectname\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
new GuardedRunnable(mContext.getExceptionHandler()) {
^
symbol:   method getExceptionHandler()

below are the versions

```
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.3",
```

I am new to React native everything was working properly but suddenly got this error which i am struggeling to fix, Please suggest if there is any solution for this or root cause.

Please let me know if more information needed.

Comment: what is your react-native version and other info (Gradle, reanimated version, etc...)

Comment: @Alirezatk please check update question with versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got this same error today and the fix which i did was

> replace

```
new GuardedRunnable(mContext.getExceptionHandler())
```

> with

```
new GuardedRunnable(mContext)
```

try and see if this works for you.

Comment: Where it will be found "GuardedRunnable"

Comment: Not an adequate answer. Please write where is the file

Comment: Please, add more information

Answer (score 1):

If you're using react-native 0.59 upgrade `react-native-reanimated` to `'v1.13.0'`

There was an issue that they fixed:
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1109

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs due to the upgrade of react native version. To solve this issue go to the android/build.gradle and past the code given below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    // ...
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
+       exclusiveContent {
+           // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
+           // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
+           // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
+           // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
+           filter {
+               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
+           }
+           forRepository {
+               maven {
+                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
+               }
+           }
+       }
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can also visit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210